# Processing video from the camera in the background

Tags: android, image-processing, video-processing

Is it possible to process (get the pixels from the camera and apply some algorithms) video in the background? That is, without actually displaying the video on the screen.

If it is possible, what are some good tutorials/examples?

Answer (score 2):

This might work. Assuming you already have a code that currently displays **camerapreview** on screen, find the line that reads something like:

```
camera.setPreviewDisplay(nameofsurface);
```

and change it to

```
camera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
```

All the camera frames will still be available in your
**public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)** method.

Incase you do not already know how to, add the following lines to 
that method in the beginning to cast the byte array as bitmap for
your processing purposes.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

                    int width = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
                    int height = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;

                    ByteArrayOutputStream outstr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    Rect rect = new Rect(0,0, width, height); 
                    YuvImage yuvimage=new YuvImage(data,ImageFormat.NV21,width,height,null);
                    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, outstr);
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outstr.toByteArray(), 0, outstr.size());
```

Comment: I tried that and it worked, but the problem is that `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` returns an immutable bmp so when I try `bmp.setPixel(1,1,Color.RED)` it thorws an IllegalStateException. How can I create a mutable Bitmap?